# AngularJS back button not working after $window.location change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-material, angularjs-ng-route

I am using the md-grid-tiles as links to new pages on a site. To give some context I have an AngularJS 1 app that is a single-page app using ng-view. So my links are all formatted with #page. Every tile is given an attribute called link and I have attached this function:

```
$scope.direct = function(tile) {
    $window.location.href = tile.link;
}
```

to the ng-click portion on my md-grid-tile:

```
<md-grid-tile ng-repeat="tile in vm.tiles track by $index"
                              md-rowspan="{{tile.span.row}}"
                              md-colspan="{{tile.span.col}}"
                              md-colspan-sm="1"
                              md-colspan-xs="1"
                              ng-class="tile.background"
                              ng-click="direct(tile)">
```

and the tile.link variable will be '#newpagetogoto'

This works as expected but the back button functionality is not there after I reroute using this method. When I press back after going to the new page it just reloads that new view and does not put me back at the home page. Is there a way to fix this?

If I use `<a>` to link to new views of my site the back button functionality works as expected, but only when I use $window.location.href does it ruin the back button functionality.

Example of using `<a>`:

```
<a href="#about" onclick="closeNav()">Our Purpose</a>
```

Any and all help is very appreciated, thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Using `<a>` does not actually keep the back button functionality, it also breaks when routing using `<a>` link.

Answer (score 0):

You must use $location instead of $window

```
$location.path(title.link)
```

Take a look $location documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: I have tried using $location.path(tile.link) but it still does not go back to the last view. Using $location will force to go back to the last url loaded, so if I were to go from google to my site and click a link to show a new view, when I click back it will take me back to google and not to the main view that has the links. Thanks for the help, I ended up adding <a> links to the grid-tiles and making them 100% width and height which allows them to click through to the new view and also return to the previous view